# What does a POST like 0x%5B%5D=somename try to achieve?

Tags: aws

We created a default environment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using their Python "sample app". After some time, the logs show a large number of POST requests with bodies like this:

```
b'0x%5B%5D=ridho'
b'0x%5B%5D=androxgh0st'
b'0x%5B%5D=Graber'
b'0x%5B%5D=anarchy99'
```

These names smell pretty fishy. I guess `%5B%5D` encodes square brackets `[]`?

Could someone explain what these people are trying to achieve?

Comment: I googled one of the names and got this as the top hit: https://thedfirreport.com/2021/02/28/laravel-debug-leaking-secrets/

Comment: @schroeder: Thanks! That matches the description nicely: "Detections: Web requests to root/.env or post data that includes **0x[]:androxgh0st** (hard coded string in smtp.py)."

Comment: I'm noticing the exact same thing - but I am capturing POST method data on my homepage to monitor what is coming in. I registered a BRAND NEW DOMAIN and this was happening within 2 hours, so clearly these bots have a way to identify new domain registrations.


array(1) {
  ["0x"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "androxgh0st"
  }
}

array(1) {
  ["0x"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Graber"
  }
}

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is simple to look up the usernames to determine the type of attack here.